# Как получить данные из адресной строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, requests

Всем привет! Как с помощью модуля `requests` получить данные из адресной строки? Спасибо.

Comment: Какой адресной строки и при чём тут requests?

Comment: ну например я сделал запрос: `requests.get('https://yandex.ru')` осществился переход по ссылке, как мне получить данные с адресной строки?

Comment: У requests нет никакой адресной строки и нет никакого перехода по ссылкам (кроме URL, который вы вписываете сами в requests.get). Вы запрашиваете URL - requests возвращает вам её содержимое - в данном случае HTML-код главной страницы Яндекса. Всё. Никаких адресных строк.

Comment: |||||ок, спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поле `rs.url` может показать итоговый адрес из запроса, причем если у запрашиваемого сайта был редирект, то `requests` это поймет и перейдет по ссылке в редиректе.

Историю переходов можно в поле `history` увидеть.

В примере я обращаюсь к `http://yandex.ru`, но в итоге был перенаправлен на `https` версию сайта. (аналогичная ситуация может быть с мобильной версией сайтов)

```
import requests
rs = requests.get('http://yandex.ru')
print(rs.url)
# https://yandex.ru/

print()
print(rs.history)
for history in rs.history:
    print(history.url)
```

Консоль:

```
https://yandex.ru/

[<Response [302]>]
http://yandex.ru/
```

Comment: спасибо, то что надо

Comment: `import telepathy`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вроде интересный модуль, нужно будет после поиграться с ним, а как его в этом вопросе использовать?

Comment: @gil9red не ожидал, что такой модуль действительно есть. Я имел в виду, что вы, похоже, телепатией владеете. Я вот не понял из вопроса, что именно за данные нужно получить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, :D

Comment: @NickVolynkin вообще я тоже понял, но, так как это довольно отдалённый аналог адресной строки и не факт что нужно было именно это, предпочёл позанудствовать в комментах)

Comment: @andreymal для меня «адресная строка» — это такое текстовое поле в браузере. Видимо, автор имел в виду «как получить то что я увижу в браузере если я введу этот URL в адресную строку браузера и нажму Enter?»